# how to describe in Makefile to compile c to obj only if the target is missing?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I 've a library in my project and I want to force gmake to build object files for this library only if the library file is not already build.

Currently, following the dependencies, the objects are always build.

So is it possible to describe such rules that will prevent compiling, if the library already exist?

added example:

```
all: prj.exe
    @echo build all.

prj.exe: main.o libbar.a
    gcc main.o -lbar -L. -o prj.exe

libbar.a: foo.o
    ar rcs libbar.a foo.o

%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: This is the default behavior of Make. Your Makefile is apparently flawed. Add it to your question so we can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you posted a makefile, what happens when you run it and what you want to happen.

Comment: If a lib source file is updated, why wouldn't you want the lib to be rebuilt? That is what would happen if the lib already is previously built. The rest of the project would be using an outdated lib, meaning if you add new functions to the lib sources, you will need to delete the outdated lib first before the makefile will compile it anew, or any new functions couldn't be used due to linker errors. I'm not sure of the motivation behind this, but it is a bad idea in my opinion.

Comment: Sure, but during the continuous integration the library is not changed and when i'm cleaning all object files I don't want to waste time with compiling library sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is with recursive make.  Any target which has no prerequisites is declared to be up to date if and only if it exists.  So, declare a library target that has no prerequisites.  Then to get make to build the object files you should use recursion.

So, something like this:

```
libfoo.a:
        @ $(MAKE) all_objects
        ...commands to build libfoo.a...

all_objects: $(OBJFILES)
```